# Окно консоли в интегрированной среде разработки

Tags: c++, консоль, app, wxwidgets

подскажите каким образом реализовано консольное окно в таких программах как Visual Studio, PyCharm, IntellIj и тому подобных программах? это отдельный виджет или текстовый виджет подогнанный под консоль, пытаюсь реализовать текстовое окно с консолью внизу с помощью wxWidgets но не знаю с чего начать

Comment: В GTK [свой виджет](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte). У VSC тоже свой (не знаю, с нуля писали или нет), потому что они регулярно хвастаются улучшениями в нем.

Comment: выходит что все они это кастомное реализация